# failed to install pyqt on my mac

Tags: python, macos, qt, pyqt

I have tried 2 ways to install `pyqt4` on my mac.
The first way is `brew install pyqt`, but it ends up with the following error:

> Warning: pyqt-4.11.4 already installed, it's just not linked

The second way is

```
cd ~/sip-4.17 
python configure.py 
make && sudo make install
cd PyQt-mac-gpl-4.12-snapshot-19cee2125593
python configure.py -d /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/ -g --use-arch x86_64
```

While it returns

> Error: qtdirs.app/Contents/MacOS/qtdirs failed to create qtdirs.out. Make sure
>   your Qt installation is correct.

Python is quite new to me, so I have no idea how to fix that and your solution means a lot to me. Thanks

Comment: Do you have Qt4 installed on your system?

Comment: Yes, I have installed QT5, but it still does't work.

Comment: If you want to use PyQt4 you need to install Qt4. For PyQt5 instead you need to install Qt5. In both cases you would need to pass the path to make to configure.py using the `--qmake` optional parameter, unless you add it to the `Path` environment variable

Comment: I use PyQt4 but I install Qt5. You mean this might be the mistake I made?

Comment: Yes. You have to either downgrade your Qt version or upgrade PyQt to PyQt5